np.fft.rfft outputs confusing result of a frequency-mixed AM wave
I am new to signal processing and trying to generate an AM wave, followed by a frequency mixer, and want to get its FFT result. I have the code like below:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# AM
fc = lambda t: np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10e6 * t)
fm = lambda t: 0.5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 3e3 * t)
f = lambda t: (1 + fm(t)) * fc(t)

# Frequency mix
fmix = lambda t: np.sin(2 * np.pi * 10e6 * t) # same to fc
f0 = lambda t: f(t) * fmix(t) + 1.5

N = 1024
FS = 2e4
T = (1.0 / FS) * N

t = np.linspace(0, T, N)
y = f0(t)
Y = np.fft.rfft(y)
Y_amp = abs(Y)
Y_amp_norm = Y_amp / N
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(N, T / N)
idx = np.argsort(freq)

plt.plot(freq[idx], Y_amp_norm[idx])
plt.show()

I think the output figure should have peaks at frequency 3e3 Hz and 0 Hz respectively. But the actual figure is like below:

The second peak is at about 400 Hz. Even adding a low-pass filter before FFT also outputs the same figure. What's wrong in the whole procedure?

I think you are just seeing carrier frequency around 500Hz (aliasing), then it is what you see around 3kHz (f = fm ± fc)

@dankal444 Could you please tell me where aliasing happened? And why is there 500Hz here?

@LittleYe233 aliasing happens because you are using 1MHz frequency in a signal sampled at about 20kHz

@dankal444 Thanks for your explanation. I have another question here: why the frequency aliasing still happened after passing a low-pass filter? I think after the filter there is no high-frequency component and only the 3kHz component is kept.

@LittleYe233 First of all, where is the filter? Second, aliasing happens the moment you calculate y. During generation of the signal
